# How can I fix the problem - - - [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ] - - -

Tags: linux-kernel

I had created my Linux distro with a tutorial on YouTube(https://youtu.be/asnXWOUKhTA) but when I go to boot it, it return:

```
- - - [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ] - - -
```

Comment: There are way too many possibilties that could have gone wrong. Try creating another kernel, and compile device drivers, file systems etc directly into the kernel rather than as modules. If it works, gradually change them back to modules until one fails.

Comment: I had already recompiled the kernel

Comment: @Paulo, please read what I have written, specifically about not building modules.

Comment: I’M not practically in this things. A small help?

Comment: Then don't try and create your own distro. Walk before you run. Install a distro and work with it for a while, including building kernels.

Comment: I already installed mint. I had tried: Ubuntu, Debian, Raspbian, Mint and elementaryOS and I know: Python, Swift, CSS, JS, SwiftUI, HTML and I’m learning C++ and C. Maybe you could misunderstand, this thing I'm saying in a calm tone no I'm saying it in a rude tone. I'm just warning you that I already know enough about Linux and computers and so I know everything that awaits me.  P.S. some word I’m translating with the translator.

Comment: So, you've installed a number of systems. Within those have you looked at the `grub.cfg` settings? Did you look at what modules `/boot/initrd` loads when it boots? Did you check what alrady loaded modules are in use? Have you ever built a new kernel from scratch? Against all those, did you try comparing them aginst the failed system?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I don't have all the distros installed. I used them some time ago. Now I only have Mint. No I never developed a kernel. I'm still learning C++. Is this site good for learning c++? learncpp.com

Comment: You do not need to know C or C++ to build a kernel, just some basic to advanced sys admin skills.

Comment: Is there a guide?